# How to create an iterator from string _and_ store it in a struct?

Tags: struct, rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to create a constructor for my struct, which would store an iterator over `String` read from file. The problem is that once the functions returns, `String` is dropped and compiler complains `new() returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`. Is there a way to associate `String` with a struct somehow so that it is not dropped after return?

I think I understand a complaint here but I don't understand how to deal with it, because I want constructor to deal both with file reading and iterator creation.

```
pub struct CharStream<'a> {
    input: std::str::Chars<'a>,
    filename: String,
}
impl<'a> CharStream<'a> {
    pub fn new(filename: String) -> CharStream<'a> {
        let mut file = File::open(&filename).unwrap();
        let mut input = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut input);
        CharStream {
            input: input.chars(), // Create an iterator over `input`
            filename: filename,
        }
        // `input` is dropped here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just store the String in the struct and create the Chars iterator on demand?

Comment: @pretzelhammer because CharStream would be a part of another iterator, which would iterate over chunks of chars (TokenIterator). So one would call next() on TokenIterator, and since it iterates over chars, it should store state somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rename `CharStream` into `FileContents` and let it own both the `filename` and `contents` of the file as `String`s. Then when you need to produce a `TokenIter` to iterate over chunks of `char`s from the `contents` you can then create the `Chars<'a>` on-demand and pass it to `TokenIter` then. Complete example:

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::str::Chars;

struct FileContents {
    filename: String,
    contents: String,
}

impl FileContents {
    fn new(filename: String) -> Self {
        let contents = fs::read_to_string(&filename).unwrap();
        FileContents { filename, contents }
    }
    fn token_iter(&self) -> TokenIter<'_> {
        TokenIter {
            chars: self.contents.chars(),
        }
    }
}

struct TokenIter<'a> {
    chars: Chars<'a>,
}

struct Token; // represents some chunk of chars

impl<'a> Iterator for TokenIter<'a> {
    type Item = Token;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.chars.next(); // call as many times as necessary to create token
        Some(Token) // return created token here
    }
}

fn example(filename: String) {
    let file_contents = FileContents::new(filename);
    let tokens = file_contents.token_iter();
    for token in tokens {
        // more processing here
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c46fdcb3dd4642a16db114648eef55b)

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of an API where FileStream (FileContents) would create and return Tokenizer (not vice versa), I think this would work for me :)

Comment: Yet I think there is one flaw here. I thought of a solution where `fn example` would directrly call `Token::new_iter(filename)` and get an iterator over iterator. In your example I need to create `FileContents` first so it is `fn example` who manages `file_contents` lifetime, not `TokenIter`.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator returned by `String::chars()` is only valid as long as the original string `input` lives. `input` is dropped at the end of `new`, so the iterator cannot be returned from the function.

To solve this, you'd want to store the `input` string in the struct as well, but then you run into other problems because one struct member can't have a reference to another member of the same struct. One reason for this is that the struct would become immovable, since moving it would invalidate the reference.

The simplest solution is probably to collect the `char`s into a `Vec<char>` and store that vector inside the `CharStream`. Then add an `usize` index and write your own `Iterator<Item = char>` implementation.

Another approach (more memory-efficient) is to store the `String` itself, and create the `Chars` iterator on demand, but that would of course result in a different API.

Solutions involving `RefCell` or similar wrappers are probably also possible.